# Android checkboxes added by code don't have the right appearance?

Tags: android, checkbox, android-drawable

I've got a really basic app in which I'm trying to insert dynamic checkboxes, and I can get them to appear, but they're not showing with the correct styling.

See below - Foo is in the LinearLayout by definition; Bar is being added programmatically.  Foo is showing with a grey box for the check, Bar is showing with a white box.

[Link to image...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i30aV.jpg)

Here's the code that's creating these:

```
for (Integer i=0; i < arArray.length;i++) {
    CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
    cb.setText("Bar");
    cb.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.black));
    cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(clListener);
    llDeckChecks.addView(cb);
}
```

I've tried setting the drawable to some android.R.drawable types, but nothing matches the Foo checkbox, so I'm entirely stumped at this point.

Comment: Are you using `AppCompatActivity`?

Comment: May be problem is in your layout positioning. Just try matchparent for width and height of your layout and then add checkbox to your layout.

Comment: @ianhanniballake - Yes, I'm using AppCompatActivity - it was the default set when I started the project.

Comment: @Sridhar - I tried setting the width and height with LayoutParams and it didn't chance the drawable.

Comment: @ctgilley post your full code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the activity context to create the button instead of the application context. If you use `getApplicationContext()` it does not extend `ContextThemeWrapper`.

Try changing

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
```

to

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox(YourActivity.this); // or getActivity() if in a fragment.
```

Comment: At one point I had been using an non-preceded "this" there, which caused the same result; I'll try prepending "this" as you've noted here.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it as well.

Answer (score 1):

AppCompat replaces the default widgets with tinted, consistent styles, as mentioned in the [Android Support Library 22.1 blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html):

> This is done automatically when inflating layouts - replacing `Button` with `AppCompatButton`, `TextView` with `AppCompatTextView`, etc. to ensure that each could support tinting.

If you'd like to create these programmatically, you can use [AppCompatCheckBox](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatCheckBox.html) in place of `Checkbox` in your code, passing in your current `Context` such as your `AppCompatActivity`.

Note: it is very important to not use `getApplicationContext()` as it does *not* have the styling information required.

Comment: Thanks - this fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.cbOutline);` where "cbOutline" is your drawable for the checkboxes outline you defined in your XML.

Comment: I don't have a defined checkbox drawable; I just want to use the default for the device/OS version.